# How non maven project can be added as a dependency in maven project

Tags: maven

One project A is added in project B as a source.
I want to add in POM.xml of project B.

1-A is non maven project.
2-B is Maven project

How non maven project can be added as a dependency in maven project as a dependency.And I don't want to run  it as a separate project and place the jar in local repository.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the "non-maven-jar" into the local (or a remote) repository. You can either build it and use `mvn install:install-file` to install it locally (or the `deploy` plugin to use a remote repository) or you need to change project A into a Maven project.

Technically, it is also possible to include a dependency by a path (`<systemPath>`), but this is not recommended.

Comment: If I place the Jar of project A in local repository then every time I have to place the Jar in local repository If it is change ?. 

This is not recommended. 
Is  there any way by which I can avoid this rather converting the project A in Maven and placing the jar every time?.

Comment: Not really. Of course, you can write a shell script or something like that. I would recommend to convert all Java projects to Maven (Gradle would be fine also in terms of compatibility). Projects without a modern build tool will always be an obstacle.